# Can't use akka in IDEA plugin development

Tags: scala, plugins, intellij-idea, akka

When I develop an IDEA plugin, I want to use `akka`, but have some problems.

I created a demo project here: https://github.com/freewind/idea-plugin-akka-demo

You can just clone it and reproduce the problem on your computer. (Notice the **Setup** section)

And I copy the problem here:

### Problems

#### 1. Can't use default akka configuration

If I removed:

- `src/main/resources/application.conf`
- `src/main/scala/freewind/MyAkkaConfig`

and run this plugin, it will report this error when starting:

```
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: 
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: No configuration setting found for key 'akka' 
[Plugin: com.yourcompany.unique.plugin.id]
```

#### 2. Can't load the configuration from file

Then I copied the `reference.conf` from akka jar, to `src/main/resources/application.conf`, but it still report the same error. Seems akka in IDEA plugin can't find this file automatically.

#### 3. ClassNotFoundException: akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler

So I have to use `MyAkkaConfig.scala` to hardcode the configuration in scala code, but this time, it reports another error:

```
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: 
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: ClassNotFoundException: akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler
[Plugin: com.yourcompany.unique.plugin.id]
```

The `akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler` is used in `MyAkkaConfig.scala`, and is included in `akka-actor_2.11:2.3.12:jar`. But why IDEA can't load it?

Comment: Sounds like classpath issue. Check your `Run Configuration` and see what classpath looks like. You can manually add directory where the config file is to classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 3rd problem, it can be fixed by passing the classloader:

```
val system = ActorSystem("my-actor", MyAkkaConfig.config, this.getClass.getClassLoader)
```

But we also can remove the `MyAkkaConfig.config`, to use the file `application.conf` under `resources`

Comment: For anyone like me facing the same issue, this also solves other two problems too, https://github.com/freewind/idea-plugin-akka-demo#fix